# Hola, estoy teniendo un problema con mi bot de discord RuntimeError:Event loop closed

Tags: python, discord.py

estoy intentando hacer un bot de bans masivos para mi server de discord porque necesito "limpiarlo" para despues archivarlo

El codigo que estoy usando es de WorkingCodeClickFork (https://gist.github.com/WorkingCodeClickFork/826fed0fabccb824ec9ea4fc86956200)

Estoy usando visual studio y python 3.10.5

No se mucho de programacion pero cualquier ayuda es recibida :)

Codigo

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot("!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

Token=" CENSORED " #bot token
Skip_Bots=False
send_on_ban=False # if True it will send a dm to the user
ban_message="You were banned!" # the message if send_on_ban is true

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for i in client.guilds: #Get all the guilds
        for m in i.members: #Get all the members inside the guild
            if m.bot and Skip_Bots!=False:
                return
            try:
                if send_on_ban==True:
                    try:
                        await m.send(ban_message)
                        print(f"Dmmed {m.display_name}")
                    except:
                        print(f"Couldn't dm {m.display_name}")
                        pass
                await m.ban(reason="Banned by banbot")
                print(f"banned {m.display_name}")
            except:
                print(f"Couldn't Ban {m.display_name}")
    print("Banning Completed")


client.run(Token)
```

Mi error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\poker\Desktop\BAN BOT\discord-ban-bot.py", line 33, in <module>
    client.run(Token)
  File "C:\Users\poker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\poker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\poker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 666, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\poker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 601, in connect
    raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000021752C42050>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\poker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\poker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\poker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 750, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\poker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Eso es todo

Comment: Aquí tienes un error sin solucionar: `discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.`

Comment: Tienes que ir al [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) y seleccionar tu bot. En la pestaña "Settings" de la izquierda selecciona "Bot". *Scrollea* hasta que veas la sección de "Privileged Gateway Intents" y habilita los 3 intents (`presence`, `server members` y `message content`)